# GCDAsyncSocket in Swift with compile error

Tags: swift, xcode6, gcdasyncsocket

I want to use `GCDAsyncSocket` in Swift, but get the "unresolved identifier 'GCDAsyncSocket'" compiler error. I have imported `GCDAsyncSocket.framework` but I can't get rid of this error.

Comment: Maybe you need to `#import` it somewhere? The bridge file has this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've added the framework to your bridging header. But have you checked to make sure the framework is added to the same targets as the Swift file you're trying to use it in?

I typically see this type of compiler error when I have a dependency in my Swift file that doesn't have matching targets. Pretty much the compiler can't think of a better way to tell you this.

Comment: I add a GCDAsyncSocket.framework to "Link Binary with libraries" and also import GCDAsyncSocket.h to bridging-Header.h. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: First, go to your Swift file. Then in Xcode, open the right-hand panel and look for "Target Membership". Take note of which targets are checked. Then in your left-hand panel in Xcode, find and click `GCDAsyncSocket.framework`. Look at the right-hand panel again and make sure the same targets are checked. If not, then make sure `GCDAsyncSocket.framework` targets match the Swift file using it.

Comment: I checked this, although target is the same, but I have error.